# how to change label text in a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a label in a div .

```
<div id="mydiv">
   <label>text</label>
</div>
```

how to write a selector to access the label and change the text .

Comment: `$('#mydiv label').text('Hello Kitty')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
$('#mydiv label').text('smtext');
```

**Update:** to change second label element in mydiv:

```
 $('#mydiv label:eq(1)').text('smtext');
```

Comment: if we have two labels how can i access the second one