# Display the result of a JQuery form in a div

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm making a calculator via a Jquery form and I'd like to display the result in a div but I can not find any solution to do it, someone would have a solution?
For the moment I use inputs to display the results.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("form#formulaire_calcul_pack").submit(function() {
           $.getJSON("wp-content/mu-plugins/calc-agri/controleur.php",
           {"actionReapro" : "calculer",
            "nombre_conso_vl_pack" : $("input#nombre_conso_vl_pack").val(),
            "nombre_jour" : $("input#nombre_jour").val(),
            "nombre_date_pack" : $("input#nombre_date_pack").val(),
            "nombre_vache" : $("input#nombre_vache").val() },
            function(data) {
                $("input#resultat_jour").val(data['resultat_jour']);
                $("input#resultat_pack_litre").val(data['resultat_pack_litre']);
                $("input#resultat_gobelet").val(data['resultat_gobelet']);
                $("input#resultat_besoin").val(data['resultat_besoin']);
            }
           );
           return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<p><i class="fa fa-tint" aria-hidden="true"></i> Je dois commander :
        <input id="resultat_pack_litre" type="text" readonly="readonly"/>
</p>   
<p><i class="fa fa-tint" aria-hidden="true"></i> Soit :
        <input id="resultat_besoin" type="text" readonly="readonly"/>
</p>
<p><i class="fa fa-tint" aria-hidden="true"></i> Soit l'&eacute;quivalent de :
        <input id="resultat_gobelet" type="text" readonly="readonly"/>
</p>
```

Comment: In English, please.

Comment: doesn't really matter, some french guys like me could answer him :)

Comment: @alexay68 You could, but that doesn't change the fact that SO is an English-only site, as per the [ask] page.

Comment: Yeah, but downvoting is a little bit rude, sending a link to check the rules isn't enough ?

Comment: @alexay68 It will actually end up deleted anyway (or translated).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change label text in a div using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250699/how-to-change-label-text-in-a-div-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ask in English

Use jquery text function.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("form#formulaire_calcul_pack").submit(function() {
           $.getJSON("wp-content/mu-plugins/calc-agri/controleur.php",
           {"actionReapro" : "calculer",
            "nombre_conso_vl_pack" : $("input#nombre_conso_vl_pack").val(),
            "nombre_jour" : $("input#nombre_jour").val(),
            "nombre_date_pack" : $("input#nombre_date_pack").val(),
            "nombre_vache" : $("input#nombre_vache").val() },
            function(data) {
                $("div#resultat_jour").text(data['resultat_jour']);
                $("div#resultat_pack_litre").text(data['resultat_pack_litre']);
                $("div#resultat_gobelet").text(data['resultat_gobelet']);
                $("div#resultat_besoin").text(data['resultat_besoin']);
            }
           );
           return false;
    });
});
```

HTML :

```
<p><i class="fa fa-tint" aria-hidden="true"></i> Je dois commander :
    <div id="resultat_pack_litre"></div>
</p>   
<p><i class="fa fa-tint" aria-hidden="true"></i> Soit :
    <divid="resultat_besoin"></div>
</p>
<p><i class="fa fa-tint" aria-hidden="true"></i> Soit l'&eacute;quivalent de :
    <div id="resultat_gobelet"></div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with `.html()` or `.text()` if you dont want to include html

Like this :

```
$(".myDiv").html(data['resultat_jour']);
$(".myDiv").text(data['resultat_jour']);
```